# text-align: -webkit-center vs text-align: center

Tags: css

Does anyone know why there is a difference between text-align: center and , text-align:-webkit-center ? For example if you have :

```
<section>
 <h1>Title<h1>
 <div class="image"></div>
</section>
```

// CSS with text-align: center;

```
section{
 text-align: center;

}
```

This will center just the text

// CSS with text-align: -webkit-center

```
section{
 text-align: -webkit-center;
}
```

This will center the text and the image.

Same goes for text-align: -moz-center;

Answer (score 16):

The text-align CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element. text-align does not control the alignment of block elements, only their inline content.

```
text-align: -moz-center;
text-align: -webkit-center;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Btw, Should I add both, -moz-center and -webkit-center, to CSS class?

Comment: What is the difference between the -moz-center and -webkit-center, on the dottoro.com document, they appear to be the same. "Text is centered".

Comment: @Quidam Yes they both do the same but "-moz-center" is compatible on firefox browser, and -"-webkit-center" is compatible on  chrome and safari.

Answer (score 12):

From the Mozilla Developer Network:

> Both WebKit and Gecko support a prefixed version of left, center, and right, that applies not only to inline content but also to block elements. This is used to implement the legacy `align` attributes on `table` elements and `<center>`. Do not use these on production Web sites.
>
> — [MDN's documentation on `text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).

Comment: If the Google homepage is using `-webkit-center` then I think its safe enough for production use...